# Получение аватарки и имени facebook

Tags: json, facebook

Я хочу получить ссылку на аватарку и имя человека по IP.
Я нашел, как получить аватарку, а с именем проблема.
Пробовал получить по такой ссылке `https://graph.facebook.com/100005995898407?арfields=name,cover` но выдает ошибку:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "Egtz07oHs1h"
   }
}
```

Comment: Хочет чтобы токен для доступа был указан в запросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Зарегистрировался в `fb`
- Зашел в https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
- Выбрал там `Tools & Support`
- Нажал на кнопку `Get Token` и после на `Get User Access Token`
- В появившемся окне поставил везде галочки, завершил диалог и в поле `Access Token:` появился сгенированный токен.

Поменял запрос, указав токен:

`https://graph.facebook.com/100005995898407?арfields=name,cover&access_token=<мой_токен>`

И получилось:

```
{
   "id": "100005995898407",
   "first_name": "Yura",
   "last_name": "Spivak",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/100005995898407/",
   "name": "Yura  Spivak",
   "updated_time": "2015-02-21T17:31:02+0000"
}
```